# Getting error with Fibonacci Function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to print the value of the fibonacci number at position 400, using memoization. At first, I was only able to print the number until the 94th position, because I got an integer overflow error. After reading online, I am now able to print the value up to position 247 by converting into BigInt. But for some reason, when I try 248 or above, I get a huge error. Here is my code:

```
(def m-fib
(memoize (fn [n]
         (condp = n
           0N 0N
           1N 1N
           (+ (m-fib (dec n)) (m-fib (- n 2)))))))

(println(m-fib 248N))
```

And here is a sample of the error I get (It's too long to put all of it into the question, and it won't specifically tell me what the problem is.

```
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
 at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
 at clojure.core$memoize$fn__5708.doInvoke(core.clj:6107)
 at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
 at fibonacci.core$_main$fn__28.invoke(core.clj:11)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
 at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
 at clojure.core$memoize$fn__5708.doInvoke(core.clj:6107)
 at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
 at fibonacci.core$_main$fn__28.invoke(core.clj:11)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
 at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
 at clojure.core$memoize$fn__5708.doInvoke(core.clj:6107)
 at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
 at fibonacci.core$_main$fn__28.invoke(core.clj:11)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
 at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
 at clojure.core$memoize$fn__5708.doInvoke(core.clj:6107)
 at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
 at fibonacci.core$_main$fn__28.invoke(core.clj:11)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
 at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
 at clojure.core$memoize$fn__5708.doInvoke(core.clj:6107)
 at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
 at fibonacci.core$_main$fn__28.invoke(core.clj:11)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
```

How can I fix this and output the fib value at position 400 without any errors?

Comment: for tail-recursive fibonacci, look [at this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939970/a-recursive-fibonacci-function-in-clojure)

Answer (score 1):

Your `m-fib` creates a tree that grows exponentially with the input.

[image: SICP distilled]

Source: http://www.sicpdistilled.com/section/1.2.2/

The space used by `m-fib` grows so large that it blows up the stack (`StackOverflow`) since all intermediate values are kept on the stack, before they are added.

Your function would work fine it is used [tail-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). This means that intermediate results are calculated every time and put on the stack. Using tail-recursion you don't need space on the stack, since only the intermediate result is stored.

I did't see a way to implement in your structure since it basically uses the stack size to calculate the answer (it spreads out to a large amount of base cases where N are 0 and 1). Here's a tail recursive other way as an example.

Some languages (like Scheme) do automatic tail-call optimization. Clojure also has limited support for tail recursion (because of limitations of the JVM) as long as you use `loop` and `recur` (as also said in the [answer by zabeltech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697042/getting-error-with-fibonacci-function-in-clojure#40697619).

In Clojure we can only use tail recursion in the tail position (last expression). This can, for example, be done by creating an iterative tail-recursive function where we pass the intermediate results along:

```
(defn m-fib [n]
  (m-fib-iter 1 0 n))

(def m-fib-iter
  (memoize
   (fn [a b count]
     (if (= count 0)
       b
       (recur (+' a b) a (- count 1)))))) ; note the +'

(fib 248) ;; => 3016128079338728432528443992613633888712980904400501N
```

Here `a` and `b` are updated every recurring round.

This answer was based on the Clojure text based on the Structure and Interpretation of Computer programs at [SICP distilled](http://www.sicpdistilled.com/section/1.2.2/). I only added memoization as you did as well, so that previously calculated answers are stored.

See that site for more information.

Answer (score 1):

@zabeltech is right, you reach the limit of the recursion.

In your case the best thing you can do without changing your code is to precall your fib function with some values lower than your desired index, to get memoized data later, instead of recursively calculating it:

```
user> (m-fib 100N)
354224848179261915075N

user> (m-fib 248N)
3016128079338728432528443992613633888712980904400501N
```

you can see that the 100th fib doesn't cause stackoverflow, and then 248th also doesn't (because it doesn't go down to 0 recursively, it only goes down to 100, and 100th value (and below) are already memoized)

Also, clojure has some much more elegant approaches to generating fibs, like this for example:

```
user> (def fibs (lazy-cat [0 1N] (map + fibs (rest fibs))))
#'user/fibs

user> (nth fibs 248)
3016128079338728432528443992613633888712980904400501N
```

Comment: Interesting observation with the memoization! :) And the `lazy-cat` one I don't see yet... How does the `map + fibs (rest fibs)` part become a Fibonacci sequence? I find the following lazy definition a bit clearer: `(defn fib
  [n]
  (nth ((fn fibgen [a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (fibgen b (+' a b))))) 0 1) n))
`. Generating Fibonacci with `fibgen` starting with a <- 0 and b <- 1 and then substituting b for a and a+b for b.

Answer (score 1):

I get a stack overflow error when I try to advance the memoization by a thousand or so (YMMV). This is because the recursion spins up a stack until it finds the largest memoized argument-> value.

Shlomi's comment refers to solutions that yield a sequence. If we want to preserve constant time access, we can build our own lazy vector. I've worked out a way to do this, whereby you supply

- an initial sequence of values and
- a function that generates the next value from the preceding however
  many.

You get a function that

- encloses a vector inside an atom that grows to reach any offered
  argument.
- And never forgets what it has done.

The function-making function is ...

```
(defn mem-vector [f inits]
  (let [mem (atom (vec inits))]
    (fn [n]
      (let [content- @mem, size- (count content-)]
        (loop [content content-, size size-]
          (if (> size n)
            (do
              (if (> size size-) (reset! mem content))
              (content n))
            (recur (conj content (apply f (subvec content (- size (count inits))))) (inc size))))))))
```

To generate fibonacci numbers,

- the initial values are `0`  and `1` and
- the function that generates the next value from the previous two is
  `+'`.

So a lazy vector of *all* the fibonacci numbers is

```
(def fibs (mem-vector +' [0 1]))
```

For example

```
(fibs 100000)
;2597406934722172416615503402127591541488048538651769658472477070395253454351127368626555677283671674475463758722307443211163839947387509103096569738218830449305228763853133492135302679278956701051276578271635608073050532200243233114383986516137827238124777453778337299916214634050054669860390862750996639366409211890125271960172105060300350586894028558103675117658251368377438684936413457338834365158775425371912410500332195991330062204363035213756525421823998690848556374080179251761629391754963458558616300762819916081109836526352995440694284206571046044903805647136346033000520852277707554446794723709030979019014860432846819857961015951001850608264919234587313399150133919932363102301864172536477136266475080133982431231703431452964181790051187957316766834979901682011849907756686456845066287392485603914047605199550066288826345877189410680370091879365001733011710028310473947456256091444932821374855573864080579813028266640270354294412104919995803131876805899186513425175959911520563155337703996941035518275274919959802257507902037798103089922984996304496255814045517000250299764322193462165366210841876745428298261398234478366581588040819003307382939500082132009374715485131027220817305432264866949630987914714362925554252624043999615326979876807510646819068792118299167964409178271868561702918102212679267401362650499784968843680975254700131004574186406448299485872551744746695651879126916993244564817673322257149314967763345846623830333820239702436859478287641875788572910710133700300094229333597292779191409212804901545976262791057055248158884051779418192905216769576608748815567860128818354354292307397810154785701328438612728620176653953444993001980062953893698550072328665131718113588661353747268458543254898113717660519461693791688442534259478126310388952047956594380715301911253964847112638900713362856910155145342332944128435722099628674611942095166100230974070996553190050815866991144544264788287264284501725332048648319457892039984893823636745618220375097348566847433887249049337031633826571760729778891798913667325190623247118037280173921572390822769228077292456662750538337500692607721059361942126892030256744356537800831830637593334502350256972906515285327194367756015666039916404882563967693079290502951488693413799125174856667074717514938979038653338139534684837808612673755438382110844897653836848318258836339917310455850905663846202501463131183108742907729262215943020429159474030610183981685506695026197376150857176119947587572212987205312060791864980361596092339594104118635168854883911918517906151156275293615849000872150192226511785315089251027528045151238603792184692121533829287136924321527332714157478829590260157195485316444794546750285840236000238344790520345108033282013803880708980734832620122795263360677366987578332625485944906021917368867786241120562109836985019729017715780112040458649153935115783499546100636635745448508241888279067531359950519206222976015376529797308588164873117308237059828489404487403932053592935976454165560795472477862029969232956138971989467942218727360512336559521133108778758228879597580320459608479024506385194174312616377510459921102486879496341706862092908893068525234805692599833377510390101316617812305114571932706629167125446512151746802548190358351688971707570677865618800822034683632101813026232996027599403579997774046244952114531588370357904483293150007246173417355805567832153454341170020258560809166294198637401514569572272836921963229511187762530753402594781448204657460288485500062806934811398276016855584079542162057543557291510641537592939022884356120792643705560062367986544382464373946972471945996555795505838034825597839682776084731530251788951718630722761103630509360074262261717363058613291544024695432904616258691774630578507674937487992329181750163484068813465534370997589353607405172909412697657593295156818624747127636468836551757018353417274662607306510451195762866349922848678780591085118985653555434958761664016447588028633629704046289097067736256584300235314749461233912068632146637087844699210427541569410912246568571204717241133378489816764096924981633421176857150311671040068175303192115415611958042570658693127276213710697472226029655524611053715554532499750843275200199214301910505362996007042963297805103066650638786268157658772683745128976850796366371059380911225428835839194121154773759981301921650952140133306070987313732926518169226845063443954056729812031546392324981793780469103793422169495229100793029949237507299325063050942813902793084134473061411643355614764093104425918481363930542369378976520526456347648318272633371512112030629233889286487949209737847861884868260804647319539200840398308008803869049557419756219293922110825766397681361044490024720948340326796768837621396744075713887292863079821849314343879778088737958896840946143415927131757836511457828935581859902923534388888846587452130838137779443636119762839036894595760120316502279857901545344747352706972851454599861422902737291131463782045516225447535356773622793648545035710208644541208984235038908770223039849380214734809687433336225449150117411751570704561050895274000206380497967960402617818664481248547269630823473377245543390519841308769781276565916764229022948181763075710255793365008152286383634493138089971785087070863632205869018938377766063006066757732427272929247421295265000706646722730009956124191409138984675224955790729398495608750456694217771551107346630456603944136235888443676215273928597072287937355966723924613827468703217858459948257514745406436460997059316120596841560473234396652457231650317792833860590388360417691428732735703986803342604670071717363573091122981306903286137122597937096605775172964528263757434075792282180744352908669606854021718597891166333863858589736209114248432178645039479195424208191626088571069110433994801473013100869848866430721216762473119618190737820766582968280796079482259549036328266578006994856825300536436674822534603705134503603152154296943991866236857638062351209884448741138600171173647632126029961408561925599707566827866778732377419444462275399909291044697716476151118672327238679208133367306181944849396607123345271856520253643621964198782752978813060080313141817069314468221189275784978281094367751540710106350553798003842219045508482239386993296926659221112742698133062300073465628498093636693049446801628553712633412620378491919498600097200836727876650786886306933418995225768314390832484886340318940194161036979843833346608676709431643653538430912157815543512852077720858098902099586449602479491970687230765687109234380719509824814473157813780080639358418756655098501321882852840184981407690738507369535377711880388528935347600930338598691608289335421147722936561907276264603726027239320991187820407067412272258120766729040071924237930330972132364184093956102995971291799828290009539147382437802779051112030954582532888721146170133440385939654047806199333224547317803407340902512130217279595753863158148810392952475410943880555098382627633127606718126171022011356181800775400227516734144169216424973175621363128588281978005788832454534581522434937268133433997710512532081478345067139835038332901313945986481820272322043341930929011907832896569222878337497354301561722829115627329468814853281922100752373626827643152685735493223028018101449649009015529248638338885664893002250974343601200814365153625369199446709711126951966725780061891215440222487564601554632812091945824653557432047644212650790655208208337976071465127508320487165271577472325887275761128357592132553934446289433258105028633583669291828566894736223508250294964065798630809614341696830467595174355313224362664207197608459024263017473392225291248366316428006552870975051997504913009859468071013602336440164400179188610853230764991714372054467823597211760465153200163085336319351589645890681722372812310320271897917951272799656053694032111242846590994556380215461316106267521633805664394318881268199494005537068697621855231858921100963441012933535733918459668197539834284696822889460076352031688922002021931318369757556962061115774305826305535862015637891246031220672933992617378379625150999935403648731423208873977968908908369996292995391977217796533421249291978383751460062054967341662833487341011097770535898066498136011395571584328308713940582535274056081011503907941688079197212933148303072638678631411038443128215994936824342998188719768637604496342597524256886188688978980888315865076262604856465004322896856149255063968811404400429503894245872382233543101078691517328333604779262727765686076177705616874050257743749983775830143856135427273838589774133526949165483929721519554793578923866762502745370104660909382449626626935321303744538892479216161188889702077910448563199514826630802879549546453583866307344423753319712279158861707289652090149848305435983200771326653407290662016775706409690183771201306823245333477966660525325490873601961480378241566071271650383582257289215708209369510995890132859490724306183325755201208090007175022022949742801823445413711916298449914722254196594682221468260644961839254249670903104007581488857971672246322887016438403908463856731164308169537326790303114583680575021119639905615169154708510459700542098571797318015564741406172334145847111268547929892443001391468289103679179216978616582489007322033591376706527676521307143985302760988478056216994659655461379174985659739227379416726495377801992098355427866179123126699374730777730569324430166839333011554515542656864937492128687049121754245967831132969248492466744261999033972825674873460201150442228780466124320183016108232183908654771042398228531316559685688005226571474428823317539456543881928624432662503345388199590085105211383124491861802624432195540433985722841341254409411771722156867086291742124053110620522842986199273629406208834754853645128123279609097213953775360023076765694208219943034648783348544492713539450224591334374664937701655605763384697062918725745426505879414630176639760457474311081556747091652708748125267159913793240527304613693961169892589808311906322510777928562071999459487700611801002296132304588294558440952496611158342804908643860880796440557763691857743754025896855927252514563404385217825890599553954627451385454452916761042969267970893580056234501918571489030418495767400819359973218711957496357095967825171096264752068890806407651445893132870767454169607107931692704285168093413311046353506242209810363216771910420786162184213763938194625697286781413636389620123976910465418956806197323148414224550071617215851321302030684176087215892702098879108938081045903397276547326416916845445627600759561367103584575649094430692452532085003091068783157561519847567569191284784654692558665111557913461272425336083635131342183905177154511228464455136016013513228948543271504760839307556100908786096663870612278690274831819331606701484957163004705262228238406266818448788374548131994380387613830128859885264201992286188208499588640888521352501457615396482647451025902530743172956899636499615707551855837165935367125448515089362904567736630035562457374779100987992499146967224041481601289530944015488942613783140087804311431741858071826185149051138744831358439067228949408258286021650288927228387426432786168690381960530155894459451808735197246008221529343980828254126128257157209350985382800738560472910941184006084485235377833503306861977724501886364070344973366473100602018128792886991861824418453968994777259482169137133647470453172979809245844361129618997595696240971845564020511432589591844724920942930301651488713079802102379065536525154780298059407529440513145807551537794861635879901158192019808879694967187448224156836463534326160242632934761634458163890163805123894184523973421841496889262398489648642093409816681494771155177009562669029850101513537599801272501241971119871526593747484778935488777815192931171431167444773882941064615028751327709474504763922874890662989841540259350834035142035136168819248238998027706666916342133424312054507359388616687691188185776118135771332483965209882085982391298606386822804754362408956522921410859852037330544625953261340234864689275060526893755148403298542086991221052597005628576707702567695300978970046408920009852106980295419699802138053295798159478289934443245491565327845223840551240445208226435420656313310702940722371552770504263482073984454889589248861397657079145414427653584572951329719091947694411910966797474262675590953832039169673494261360032263077428684105040061351052194413778158095005714526846009810352109249040027958050736436961021241137739717164869525493114805040126568351268829598413983222676377804500626507241731757395219796890754825199329259649801627068665658030178877405615167159731927320479376247375505855052839660294566992522173600874081212014209071041937598571721431338017425141582491824710905084715977249417049320254165239323233258851588893337097136310892571531417761978326033750109026284066415801371359356529278088456305951770081443994114674291850360748852366654744869928083230516815711602911836374147958492100860528981469547750812338896943152861021202736747049903930417035171342126923486700566627506229058636911882228903170510305406882096970875545329369434063981297696478031825451642178347347716471058423238594580183052756213910186997604305844068665712346869679456044155742100039179758348979935882751881524675930878928159243492197545387668305684668420775409821781247053354523194797398953320175988640281058825557698004397120538312459428957377696001857497335249965013509368925958021863811725906506436882127156815751021712900765992750370228283963962915973251173418586721023497317765969454283625519371556009143680329311962842546628403142444370648432390374906410811300792848955767243481200090309888457270907750873638873299642555050473812528975962934822878917619920725138309388288292510416837622758204081918933603653875284116785703720989718832986921927816629675844580174911809119663048187434155067790863948831489241504300476704527971283482211522202837062857314244107823792513645086677566622804977211397140621664116324756784216612961477109018826094677377686406176721484293894976671380122788941309026553511096118347012565197540807095384060916863936906673786627209429434264260402902158317345003727462588992622049877121178405563348492490326003508569099382392777297498413565614830788262363322368380709822346012274241379036473451735925215754757160934270935192901723954921426490691115271523338109124042812102893738488167358953934508930697715522989199698903885883275409044300321986834003470271220020159699371690650330547577095398748580670024491045504890061727189168031394528036165633941571334637222550477547460756055024108764382121688848916940371258901948490685379722244562009483819491532724502276218589169507405794983759821006604481996519360110261576947176202571702048684914616894068404140833587562118319210838005632144562018941505945780025318747471911604840677997765414830622179069330853875129298983009580277554145435058768984944179136535891620098725222049055183554603706533183176716110738009786625247488691476077664470147193074476302411660335671765564874440577990531996271632972009109449249216456030618827772947750764777446452586328919159107444252320082918209518021083700353881330983215894608680127954224752071924134648334963915094813097541433244209299930751481077919002346128122330161799429930618800533414550633932139339646861616416955220216447995417243171165744471364197733204899365074767844149929548073025856442942381787641506492878361767978677158510784235702640213388018875601989234056868423215585628508645525258377010620532224244987990625263484010774322488172558602233302076399933854152015343847725442917895130637050320444917797752370871958277976799686113626532291118629631164685159934660693460557545956063155830033697634000276685151293843638886090828376141157732003527565158745906567025439437931104838571313294490604926582363108949535090082673154497226396648088618041573977888472892174618974189721700770009862449653759012727015227634510874906948012210684952063002519011655963580552429180205586904259685261047412834518466736938580027700252965356366721619883672428226933950325930390994583168665542234654857020875504617520521853721567282679903418135520602999895366470106557900532129541336924472492212436324523042895188461779122338069674233980694887270587503389228395095135209123109258159006960395156367736067109050566299603571876423247920752836160805597697778756476767210521222327184821484446631261487584226092608875764331731023263768864822594691211032367737558122133470556805958008310127481673962019583598023967414489867276845869819376783757167936723213081586191045995058970991064686919463448038574143829629547131372173669836184558144505748676124322451519943362182916191468026091121793001864788050061351603144350076189213441602488091741051232290357179205497927970924502479940842696158818442616163780044759478212240873204124421169199805572649118243661921835714762891425805771871743688000324113008704819373962295017143090098476927237498875938639942530595331607891618810863505982444578942799346514915952884869757488025823353571677864826828051140885429732788197765736966005727700162592404301688659946862983717270595809808730901820120931003430058796552694788049809205484305467611034654748067290674399763612592434637719995843862812391985470202414880076880818848087892391591369463293113276849329777201646641727587259122354784480813433328050087758855264686119576962172239308693795757165821852416204341972383989932734803429262340722338155102209101262949249742423271698842023297303260161790575673111235465890298298313115123607606773968998153812286999642014609852579793691246016346088762321286205634215901479188632194659637483482564291616278532948239313229440231043277288768139550213348266388687453259281587854503890991561949632478855035090289390973718988003999026132015872678637873095678109625311008054489418857983565902063680699643165033912029944327726770869305240718416592070096139286401966725750087012218149733133695809600369751764951350040285926249203398111014953227533621844500744331562434532484217986108346261345897591234839970751854223281677187215956827243245910829019886390369784542622566912542747056097567984857136623679023878478161201477982939080513150258174523773529510165296934562786122241150783587755373348372764439838082000667214740034466322776918936967612878983488942094688102308427036452854504966759697318836044496702853190637396916357980928865719935397723495486787180416401415281489443785036291071517805285857583987711145474240156416477194116391354935466755593592608849200546384685403028080936417250583653368093407225310820844723570226809826951426162451204040711501448747856199922814664565893938488028643822313849852328452360667045805113679663751039248163336173274547275775636810977344539275827560597425160705468689657794530521602315939865780974801515414987097778078705357058008472376892422189750312758527140173117621279898744958406199843913365680297721208751934988504499713914285158032324823021340630312586072624541637765234505522051086318285359658520708173392709566445011404055106579055037417780393351658360904543047721422281816832539613634982525215232257690920254216409657452618066051777901592902884240599998882753691957540116954696152270401280857579766154722192925655963991820948894642657512288766330302133746367449217449351637104725732980832812726468187759356584218383594702792013663907689741738962252575782663990809792647011407580367850599381887184560094695833270775126181282015391041773950918244137561999937819240362469558235924171478702779448443108751901807414110290370706052085162975798361754251041642244867577350756338018895379263183389855955956527857227926155524494739363665533904528656215464288343162282921123290451842212532888101415884061619939195042230059898349966569463580186816717074818823215848647734386780911564660755175385552224428524049468033692299989300783900020690121517740696428573930196910500988278523053797637940257968953295112436166778910585557213381789089945453947915927374958600268237844486872037243488834616856290097850532497036933361942439802882364323553808208003875741710969289725499878566253048867033095150518452126944989251596392079421452606508516052325614861938282489838000815085351564642761700832096483117944401971780149213345335903336672376719229722069970766055482452247416927774637522135201716231722137632445699154022395494158227418930589911746931773776518735850032318014432883916374243795854695691221774098948611515564046609565094538115520921863711518684562543275047870530006998423140180169421109105925493596116719457630962328831271268328501760321771680400249657674186927113215573270049935709942324416387089242427584407651215572676037924765341808984312676941110313165951429479377670698881249643421933287404390485538222160837088907598277390184204138197811025854537088586701450623578513960109987476052535450100439353062072439709976445146790993381448994644609780957731953604938734950026860564555693224229691815630293922487606470873431166384205442489628760213650246991893040112513103835085621908060270866604873585849001704200923929789193938125116798421788115209259130435572321635660895603514383883939018953166274355609970015699780289236362349895374653428746875N
```

It ran out of heap space when I tried `1000000` :(.

A more readable example is ...

```
(map fibs (range 20))
;(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181)
```

The point is that this function gives you constant time access to an already found value. You don't have to run down a sequence.

---

Edited to correct an error whereby the buffer (correctly) expanded and (wrongly) contracted with each offered argument.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably because you reached the maximum recursion limit. In order to go around this one could rewrite the function to be tail recursive and then use the [loop-recur](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop) pattern.

Comment: How can I implement loop-recur with my current code? Can you provide an example