# lazily calling functions for infinite sequence clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, fibonacci

I am very new to clojure and want to make *obvious* programs.

`(def fib (conj fib (apply + (take-last 2 fib))))` Doesn't work because of no lazy evaluation, nor indication of the start being `[0 1]`

`(def fib ( (fn [array] (recur (conj array (apply + (take-last 2 array))))) [0 1]))` And here `recur` is seemingly not lazily evaluated.

Highly related to ( [a recursive Fibonacci function in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939970/a-recursive-fibonacci-function-in-clojure) )
however they use loops and counts or multi-arity. I was wondering if this problem was possible without this.

[`(def fib (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + fib (rest fib))))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8946738/22863450) is a very nice solution but somehow hides the operation of f<sub>x</sub> = f<sub>x-1</sub> + f<sub>x-2</sub>, rather a shift and add all elements. Elegant but not so obvious to the original fibonacci definition.

Is there a way to avoid using map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*obvious* is going to be highly subjective, but perhaps this can give you some ideas:

```clj
user> (def fib ((fn f [a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (f b (+ a b))))) 0 1))
#'user/fib
user> (take 10 fib)
(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
```

Comment: This is great. Could you help me, why does `(def fib ( (fn f [array] (f (lazy-seq (conj array (apply + (take-last 2 array)))))) [0 1])) ` not work, with it using arrays and `conj` instead of the args and `cons`

Comment: There are several reasons that code does not work. The first reason is that in your definition of `f`, the first thing `f` does is call `f`, and then that invocation of `f` immediate calls `f`, and that happens many times until you run out of stack space. It's important in the one I wrote that the call to `f` is inside the `lazy-seq`. Also, your new one (if it weren't blowing out the stack) would be operating on a larger and larger array each invocation (!) - also not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to skin a cat but using `lazy-seq` to implement the Fibonacci sequence is arguably the prettiest. But the `iterate` function is also not that bad.

Here are three implementations of the Fibonacci sequence that all produce lazy sequences with increasing degree of ugliness.

```
(defn fib
  ([] (fib 0 1))
  ([a b]
   (lazy-seq
    (cons a (fib b (+ a b))))))

(take 20 (fib))
;; => (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181)

(defn fib2 []
  (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [0 1])))

(take 20 (fib2))
;; => (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181)

(defn fib3 []
  (iterator-seq
   (let [state (atom [0 1])]
     (reify java.util.Iterator
       (hasNext [_] true)
       (next [_] (ffirst (swap-vals!
                          state
                          (fn [[a b]]
                            [b (+ a b)]))))))))

(take 20 (fib3))
;; => (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181)
```

But I wouldn't recommend the last one that creates a Java iterator and wraps it with `iterator-seq`. But I nevertheless included it to show the strong connection between Clojure lazy sequences and Java iterators.